# When using multiple bootstrap modals on a single page (not displaying them at the same time) only the first modal works

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms, modal-dialog

I am having a strange problem and have spent the majority of the last 4 working hours trying to figure this out. I have read most of the similar questions on here but they are either not working due to a div mismatch or are wanting to open one modal from another.

I have a gridview containing data records with 3 link buttons in a template field. 2 of these buttons need to call up a modal where the user can either view more details or cancel the record.

The problem I am facing is that whichever modals code I put first in the aspx page, that modal displays correctly. Any modals after that only displays the black overlay.

I have read somewhere that this may be due to the z-index but I have not been able to get this working. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Gridview Markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvEnquiries" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EnquiryID">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EnquiryID" DataField="EnquiryID" Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Enquiry No" DataField="EnquiryNo" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="EType" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Company" DataField="Company" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Assigned To" DataField="AssignedTo" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address By" DataField="AddressBy" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy}" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Enquiry Date" DataField="EnquiryDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy}" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-info" ID="btnView" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" ToolTip="View Details" OnClick="btnView_Click"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-info" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" ToolTip="Create Quote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-info" ID="btnCloseEnq" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" ToolTip="Close Enquiry" OnClick="btnCloseEnq_Click"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

The modals are being called from code side using the following line of code, obviously changing the ID for the seperate calls:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "none", "<script>$('#CloseEnq').modal('show');</script>", false);
```

The actual markup for the 2 modals are:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="ViewEnqDetail" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-mid modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updViewEnqModal" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblViewEnqTitle"></asp:Label></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
****Body Content In Here*******
</div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and

```
<div class="modal fade" id="CloseEnq" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-mid modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"></asp:Label></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="container-fluid">

                            </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another 7 hours I have finally found the culprit.

The order in which the tags were closed were incorrect. The body div was only being closed after the update panel and its content div was.

Comment: I am having similar issue but was not able to resolve this. I am using a Bootstrap Modal Form instead of an UpdatePanel. Do you know if this should work?